# Create and Get Custom Roles and assign them to users

Tags: fusionauth

I can't understand how to create custom roles in fusionauth. I want to create my own set of `roles` and put them in respective `groups`.

Are `roles` and `groups` are synonymous in fusionauth ? I see `roleIds` object inside `groups` but can't find much detailed documentation on that.

Also `jwt` token has `roles[]`. Is it possible to return those custom roles in `jwt token`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [UI](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/tutorials/create-an-application) or the [API](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/applications) to create roles for an application. When you create an Application in FusionAuth you may create the roles at the same time. The UI link above is a tutorial to create an application in the UI.

The roles for the default application `FusionAuth` cannot be modified. This application represents the admin user interface. You will create at least one application that represents your application.

> Are `roles` and `groups` are synonymous in fusionauth ?

No. Roles belong to an Application. An application in FusionAuth represents and authenticate resource. A Group is a logical grouping of users, and a way to manage roles across multiple applications.

To manage roles for an Application once it has been created navigate to the Application Roles. `Settings --> Applications --> Manage Roles` The Manage Roles button is the dark blue one in the row action.

The FusionAuth Group can be used to assign roles from multiple applications to a user through Group membership.

For example, assume you have multiple Applications, `Support Portal` and `Workday`, and each of these applications contains an `admin` role.

A FusionAuth Group could be created called `Admins` and it would be assigned the `admin` role from `Support Portal` and `Workday`.

A User can be assigned the `admin` role for both of these Applications through Group membership. The user will still require a registration to the application to receive the roles assigned to the Group. This mechanism provides a way to manage role assignment for groupings of users.

The `roleIds` inside of the `Group` object is how the API will interact with Application Roles. If you utilize the UI you can just point and click.

> Also `jwt` token has `roles[]`. Is it possible to return those custom roles in jwt token?

The roles assigned directly through a User Registration or by Group Membership will come back in the JWT in the `roles` claim when logging into a specific Application.